# What does 被打败 mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

At the zoo feeding a bear 喂大熊
convo:
-它是被打败的那一块
-它被打败了呀
-有点可怜
-多给它几块肉吧

dictionary only gives "to defeat / to overpower / to beat / to be defeated"

Comment: According to the context, it should be "has been defeated/ has lost in battle".

Comment: @Archeosudoerus lost in battle, OK thanks

Comment: PS: "它是被打败的那一块" does not look correct. According to the context "it" is a bear. The classifier for bear should be "个" (general for objects) or "头" (commonly used for big animals), not "块".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the big bad bears don't let the poor little bear get any meat?

它是被打败的那一块
He didn't get that bit.
-它被打败了呀
Yeah he lost that one
-有点可怜
I feel sorry for him.
-多给它几块肉吧
Give him some more meat.

Answer (score 1):

"打败" means to defeat.

"被打败" means to be defeated, to have been defeated.

"它被打败了呀": It is defeated! It has been defeated!

Answer (score 1):

I post this piece of explanation for your reference.
A打败了B   A is the winner.
A被打败了  A lost, A is the loser.